# Taking too much time in loading news from rss feed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am working in a news app. I have six different news. I am calling the rss feeds from viewwillappear() method. I have run a switch case with the selectedIndex. I included lazy loading but still it takes a huge time to load news from rss. 
Any probabale solutions? 
Thanks in advance

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    noNewsLabel.hidden=YES;
    bdNewsParser=[[[BDNewsParser alloc] init]retain];
    if (loadingFlag==1)
    {
        ImgesName=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        dicImages_msg = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    }
    if (loadingFlag!=2)
    {
        NSLog(@"newsTypeInd:%@",newsTypeInd);
        [newsCat setText:[newsTypeInd objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];

        [newsTitleArray removeAllObjects];
        [newsDescriptionArray removeAllObjects];
        [newsLinkArray removeAllObjects];
        [newsPublicationDate removeAllObjects];
        [newsImageLinkArray removeAllObjects];
        [newsSourceArray removeAllObjects];

        switch(selectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                 [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/itnews.php"];
                break;
            case 1: 
                [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/internationalnews.php"];
                break;
            case 2: 
              //   [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/bangladeshnews.php"];
                [self showAlert];

                break;
            case 3: 
                //[bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/businessnews.php"];
                [self showAlert];

                break;
            case 4: 
                [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/entertainmentnews.php"];
                break;
            case 5: 
                  [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/sportnews.php"];
                break;
           default:
                break;
        }


        newsTitleArray=bdNewsParser.titleArray;
        newsDescriptionArray=bdNewsParser.descriptionArray;
        newsLinkArray=bdNewsParser.linkArray;
        newsPublicationDate=bdNewsParser.publicationDateArray;
        newsImageLinkArray=bdNewsParser.newsImageArray;
        newsSourceArray=bdNewsParser.newsSourceArray;
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        // [self filterArrayGroupWise:selectedIndex];


        if ([newsTitleArray count]==0) {
            NSLog(@"Hide contrrol");
            [self hideControls];
            noNewsLabel.hidden=NO;
        }
        else {
            [self showControls];
            noNewsLabel.hidden=YES;
            [self setupScrollview];

            ImgesName = newsImageLinkArray;
            [self reloadScrolview];
        }

        savedTitleArr=[userDefault readArrayFromUserDefaults:@"FavoriteTitle"];
        if (savedTitleArr)
        {
            if ([savedTitleArr containsObject:[newsTitleArray objectAtIndex:pageNo]])
            {
                [saveButton setEnabled:NO];
            }
            else
            {
                [saveButton setEnabled:YES];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [saveButton setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }

    indicatorAnimatingFlag=0;
    [activityView stopAnimating];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    pageNo=0;
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView setBounds:frame];
    [bdNewsParser release];
    index=0;
    selectedIndex=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "Lazy Loading", but where? It seems to me that you make the call and then you try to access its value:

```
case 0:
      [bdNewsParser loadXMLByURL:@"http://amarhost.info/fuad/newsainment/itnews.php"];
      break;
```

And then:

```
 newsTitleArray=bdNewsParser.titleArray;
        newsDescriptionArray=bdNewsParser.descriptionArray;
        newsLinkArray=bdNewsParser.linkArray;
        newsPublicationDate=bdNewsParser.publicationDateArray;
        newsImageLinkArray=bdNewsParser.newsImageArray;
        newsSourceArray=bdNewsParser.newsSourceArray;
```

Comment: I didn't gave you concrete answer. Just pointed that you are not "lazy loading" anything. The right term would be to do an "async task". "Lazy loading" is to do something when you actually need it.

Comment: I took an activity indicator  which animates till the news and image are loaded after that the activity indicator is stopped.                      [activityView startAnimating];                            [activityView stopAnimating];

Comment: ** Finally I have solve it using perform selector **

 
`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    indexNo=selectedIndex;
    newsCat.text=[newsTypeInd objectAtIndex:indexNo];
    self.initialActivityIndicatorView.hidden=NO;
      [self.initialActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    dateLabel.text=nil;
    
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
          [self performSelector:@selector(viewWillAppearForFlag0) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

`